# Apollo Client: refetch data with modified variables, useQuery or useLazyQuery?

Tags: javascript, apollo-client

I have a table showing data from server. The data is retrieved using Apollo Client query.

The table has multiple filters and a search box. And all filters and text in the search are save in local storage.

The table and the fetch works like:

1. read from `localstorage`, build variables for fetch (offset, limit, ...)
2. fetch with variables
3. when filters or search change, refetch with modified variables
4. also save the modified variables to `localstorage`

My question is: should I use `useQuery` or `useLazyQuery` for this purpose.

With `useQuery`, I may could do:

```js
// first fetch
const {data, loading, refetch} = useQuery(gql, { variables: {...filters from localstorage} })

// when filters changed
useEffect(() => {
  refetch({variable: {...changed filters}})
}, [filters])
```

For modified filters, is it possible to do `refetch({variables: {...modified filters}})`?

And with `useLazyQuery`, I may do:

```js
const [getData, {data, loading, refetch}] = useLazyQuery(gql)

// first fetch
useEffect(() => {
  getData({variables: {...filters from localstorage}})
}, [])

// when filters changed
useEffect(() => {
  refetch({variable: {...changed filters}}) // ?
  // or
  getData({variables: {...modified filters}}) // ?
}, [filters])
```

`refetch` or `getData`, which should I use?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should just use *useQuery*, but instead of keeping your *filters* in localeStorage, keep it also in a local React state. So when you update the filters state, useQuery will know and refetch the query with new parameters. And you don't need separate useEffect to trigger the refetch.